# Create an automation to start/stop RDS/Elastic Search in AWS SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-rds, aws-ssm

AWS System Manager Provides a way to start/stop ec2 instances with default automation documents AWS-StartEC2Instance, AWS-StopEC2Instance. Similar to this I want to create an automation to start/stop rds and elastic search instances. Not able to find relevant resources.

Answer (score 0):

For RDS, you can use [AWS Instance Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler-on-aws/) or [a more simpler solution based on Lambda and Eventbridge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/schedule-amazon-rds-stop-and-start-using-aws-lambda/).

You cannot stop and restart OpenSearch's instances, you can only delete and recreate the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can stop/start AWS OpenSearch(Elasticsearch) cluster.

Here's couple of ideas to achieve this for RDS:

**Use AWS System Manager Document:**

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/schedule-amazon-rds-stop-and-start-using-aws-systems-manager/

**Bash + awscli + access keys or IAM role:**

- access key: if executing from local/on-prem
- IAM role: if within AWS (e.g. EC2 instance)
- Use cron to schedule the stop/start

**Lambda Function:**

- Use [Lambda function URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html) which you can invoke like an API
- Use EventBridge to schedule the stop/start

Comment: Can we do this for elastic cache?

Comment: No, unfortunately you also cannot stop/start ElastiCache.